# Stitching together irregular rasters into an XArray dataset that's too large for memory

Tags: dask, hdf5, python-xarray

I'm working on a project that involves many layers of raster data over a large area.  This data is currently being stored in a set of raster files, each covering a small irregular polygon.  I'd like to stitch these together into a large XArray dataset (too big for memory) that I'll access through dask.  Is there a slick way to do this?

I've tried creating an empty dask dataarray to start with and then iteratively merging in the polygons, but this process is slower than you'd expect and overloads my machine's memory.  My next approach hand writing a method that saves the results pixel-by-pixel in an hdf5 file, but I thought I'd check to see if there's a higher-level approach first.

Comment: Perhaps https://blog.dask.org/2021/12/01/mosaic-fusion has some hints?